# Check array values are all different

Tags: javascript

I have this code that generates 6 different numbers ( 1 - 6 ), and displays the percentage of rolls that are all different. The percentages do not add up and display correctly.

```js
var values = [ Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 ];
var different = 0;
var same = 0;

if (values[0] != values[1] != values[2] != values[3] != values[4] != values[5]) {
    different += 1 ; }
else {
   same += 1; 
}
console.log((different/(same+different))*100 + "% of rolls are completely different");
```

Comment: can you post a code without an interval?

Comment: Your if statement is wrong. It doesn't mean what you want it to.

Comment: You have a trailing comma in your values array. Removing that does make the function run, but it doesn't seem to be a well constructed function and should be rewritten.

Comment: You should maybe read your console and see that your `if` is wrong

Comment: `values[4] != values[5]) {`  use instead of `values[4] != (values[5]) {` this in the if condition. last `value[5]` is wrongly declare

Comment: @prasad some guy edited the code. it was this `values[4] != values[5]) { `before

Comment: Discover [Array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var values = [ Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1, Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1, Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1, Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1, Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1, Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1 ];

console.log(values);

var nums = new Set(values);
var uniqueVals = nums.size;

console.log('% age of unique values: ' + uniqueVals*100/values.length);
```

Use a set to find out how many values are same.

Answer (score 0):

A slight reworking of the code to give a better structure. I also added a console log of the array so you can see the numbers that are pushed into it. The basic premise is that a randome number is generated and if it does not exist in the array already - the different count is incremented. Then its just a case of dividing the different count by the length of the array to get hte percentage of changed rolls.

```js
var values = [];
var different = 0;
var same = 0;

for(i=0; i<6; i++){
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
  if(values.indexOf(num) == -1){different++};
  values.push(num);
}

console.log(values);
console.log(different + '/' + values.length + " (" + (different/values.length)*100 + "%) of rolls are completely different");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put all array's values into the object as keys. As an object can't have the keys with the same name, repeated keys will be thrown away. Then we can find the percentage of unique values in the array by comparing array's length to keys number in the object.

```
var values = [ Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 ];
console.log(values);
var obj = {};
values.forEach(function(val) {
    obj[val] = true;
});
var difference = Math.round((Object.keys(obj).length/values.length) * 100) 
console.log(difference + ' % of rolls are completely different')
```